# Linking searches together in php

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms, checkbox

I want to link searches from a checkbox form together. E.g i have 5 checkboxes (a,b,c,d,e) if i have checked a and b, i want to search depending on what i have searched i.e display two different results.

```
 <form role="form" action="R.php" method="post">
  <div class="form-group">
  <input type="checkbox" value="a" name="search" />a

    <input type="checkbox" value="b" name="search" />b

      <input type="checkbox" value="c" name="search" />c

        <input type="checkbox" value="d" name="search" />d

          <input type="checkbox" value="e" name="search" />e
          </div>
  <input class="btn btn-default glyphicon-align-right" type="submit" value=">>"/>
  </form>
```

The PHP

```
 <?php $output='';

if(isset($_POST['search'])){
$searchq=$_POST['search'];
$searchq = preg_replace ("#[^0-9a-z]#i","",$searchq);   

$Squery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM database WHERE Name LIKE '%$searchq%'");


$count = mysql_num_rows ($Squery);

    echo "<div id=results><ul class=list-group><div id=qwerty>";
if($count == 0){
$output = 'There was no results!';
}else{

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($Squery)){
        $name = $row ['Name'];
        $id  = $row['ID'];
        $category = $row['Category'];
        $output .='<div class="container">'.$name.$category.'       '.$id.'</div>';

        echo  "<li>"."<div style=height:95px ><h3 class=text-center style=text-transform:capitalize >".$name.' '."</h3></div>".
        "<div>"."<a href=n.php><img src=images/$id.jpg alt=Image /></a>
                    </div>".



        ' '.$category.' RESULT!!!!!'.$id."</li>";



    }
        echo "</div></ul></div>";
}
}
?>
```

Comment: if a, b, and c are all chosen, do you want to search where name = '%abc%' or where name = a OR name = b OR name = c?

Comment: when a, b and c are all chosen. For example choosing letter A will give me some results starting with letter A, choosing B will give me results ending in letter B but if i check A and B i want results starting with letter A and letter B. this is just an example of how this kind of works

Comment: found the reason that it may be that it can only read one word at one time... but still cannot find solution. :)

Comment: What I think you want to use is an OR statement in your SQL. So for the instance of 'abc' being chosen, name LIKE %abc% OR name LIKE %b OR LIKE name like a%

Comment: do you know how to do this with a search field as well.. when i search 'a b'... i does not read b and only reads a (basically the first word i typed in the search field). i don't want to write LIKE %a OR %b because later on my search will be a lot greater than this and it will make me write a lot of %etc with a much greater search. thanks for your help:)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question correctly, you would want to be able to search for all results that match the checkboxes that you have checked.

I'm not sure exactly what results you would be looking for, so instead I'll give you a few different options and let you take it from there.

First, in order to pass MORE THAN ONE checkbox to your PHP script, you need to define you checkboxes differently.

```
<form role="form" action="R.php" method="post">
  <div class="form-group">
      <input type="checkbox" value="a" name="search[]" />a

      <input type="checkbox" value="b" name="search[]" />b

      <input type="checkbox" value="c" name="search[]" />c 

      <input type="checkbox" value="d" name="search[]" />d
      <input type="checkbox" value="e" name="search[]" />e
  </div>
  <input class="btn btn-default glyphicon-align-right" type="submit" value=">>"/>
```

Notice the brackets after "search" .. name = "search[]". This allows your checkboxes to pass over a COLLECTION of values, instead of just one.

Secondly, on your PHP side.

Once you submit your checkboxes, you will want to get them the same way you currently do:

```
$searches = $_POST['search'];
```

$searches will now be an array filled with the values that were checked in your form.

Depending on your desired result, what you do next would look something like this.

Let's take the case that A and B were checked.

If you want to get all results where the word begins with the letter A OR the word begins with the letter B:

```
<?php 

    $searches = $_POST['searches'];
    $Squery = "SELECT * FROM database";
    $Swhere = ""; 

    //add all your individual searches by looping through the checkbox values
    foreach($searches as $search){
        $Swhere .= " OR name LIKE '%$search' ";
    }

    //remove the first OR case, because it is not needed for the first search query
    $Swhere = ltrim($Swhere, ' OR');

    //add your dynamic where statement to your query
    $Squery .= $Swhere

    $result = mysql_query($Squery);
    //...... run the query and get the results the same way you are
```

By using the foreach function, your can add all the checkboxes you want to your search, but the query on the PHP side will not have to change at all.

On a similar note, in the case of A selected and B selected, if you want to get all words that begin with A, begin with B, OR begin with AB, then your code would be adjusted like so:

```
<?php 

    $searches = $_POST['searches'];

    //this takes your array of values and combines them into one word.
    //your searches variable remains an array, but your stringSearch is now
    //a word with the combined values
    $stringSearch = implode($searches,'');

    $Squery = "SELECT * FROM database";
    $Swhere = " name LIKE '%$stringSearch%' "; 

    //add all your individual searches by looping through the checkbox values
    foreach($searches as $search){
        $Swhere .= " OR name LIKE '%$search' ";
    }

    //add your dynamic where statement to your query
    $Squery .= $Swhere

    $result = mysql_query($Squery);
    //...... run the query and get the results the same way you are
```

Hopefully you can take this example and adjust to what your actual needs are.

One thing to note, is you SHOULD NOT be using mysql_query. It is opening your code up to major SQL injection concerns. I only used it above to display how you would do it with your current code. Look into the [mysqli](http://www.pontikis.net/blog/how-to-use-php-improved-mysqli-extension-and-why-you-should) functions